# Deny burp suite interception on server response

Tags: intercept, burp

Can you any body suggest me how to deny the burp suite intercept the server response to the web client?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142502/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-posted-form-data-when-the-form-submit-is-intercepted)?
One can even argue that your question could be a dupicate of the attached link. Have a look anyway.
>I know, that this does not even qualify as a valid answer, but SO won't let me comment, so I've had to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to intercept and drop server responses which is defaulted Off and includes and exclude for [certain types of files](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-XCYvX9_ph0s/U3uCGh5UJNI/AAAAAAAABns/T422OYJXMs4/s1600/15.jpg). Make sure intercept is turned on for Responses and the file is not excluded. Once you are intercepting the responses you can use the [drop button](https://portswigger.net/sc/Proxy_GettingStartedWithBurpProxy_4.png).